# Dynamic load balancing with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, server, devops, load-balancing

I'm new in kubernetes.

We have 50 ip addresses and ip addresses have a request limit. The limit is a value kept in the database. We want load balancer to choose it based on the one that has the most limits in the database. Can Kubernetes do that?

Comment: The standard Kubernetes objects will never look at your application-specific databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I advice you to read official documentation about networking in Kubernetes - you can find it here: [kubernetes-networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/). Especially read about [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). Original Load Balancer in Kubernetes never checks application-specific databases.

> An abstract way to expose an application running on a set of
> [Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) as a network service. With Kubernetes you don't need to modify your application to use an unfamiliar service discovery mechanism. Kubernetes gives Pods their own IP addresses and a single DNS name for a set of Pods, and can
> load-balance across them.

Example on service type [clusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

> Kubernetes assigns a stable, reliable IP address to each newly-created
> Service (the
> [ClusterIP](https://v1-16.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#servicespec-v1-core)) from the cluster's pool of [available Service IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#ip-allocation).   Kubernetes also assigns a hostname to the ClusterIP, by adding a [DNS entry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns).  The ClusterIP and hostname are unique within the cluster and do not  change throughout the lifecycle of the Service. Kubernetes only
> releases the ClusterIP and hostname if the Service is deleted from the cluster's configuration. You can reach a healthy Pod running your application using either the ClusterIP or the hostname of the Service.

Take a look how it looks in GKE: [GKE-IP-allocation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#ip-allocation).

> You can specify also your own cluster IP address as part of a
> `Service`  creation request - set the  `.spec.clusterIP`  field.
>
> The IP address that you choose must be a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address from within the  `service-cluster-ip-range`  CIDR range that is configured for the API server. If you try to create a Service with an  invalid clusterIP address value, the API server will return a 422 HTTP status code to indicate that there's a problem.

To sum up. Kubernetes load balancer never does deep dive into your app. To connect to your app you need to create service. Kubernetes assigns a stable, reliable IP address to each newly-created Service from which you can access your app within or from outside the cluster. You can also manually assign IP per service.

Comment: Good to hear that. If my answer was useful please consider accepting and upvoting it to be more visible for community.

Comment: I accepted. But votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Thanks again, have a nice day.